# How can I get list of all product/category fields in Magento 2?

Tags: database, magento-2.1

I need to **display all fields (column names) from product/category**.
How can i do that?

Get instance and then *foreach as key => value* is a bad idea.

Comment: When you say fields, do you mean attributes or actual columns in the database?

Comment: actual columns. OK. Let's take cms pages. How can i get fields (names) list of it?

Comment: see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using this in a resource model:

```
$fields = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->describeTable($this->getTable('cms/page');
```

This is a pattern that the core team uses; `fields` will be an array with the column names of `cms_page` as the keys. You can then iterate, print, or do whatever with them.

This is equivalent to running a SQL query like:

```
DESCRIBE `cms_page`;
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: it really works for cms pages. But is it possible do similar thing with product? Or i need to get description of each table separately and then merge arrays?

Comment: @vapry yes, you'll probably have to do that for EAV-based or multi-table entities, unfortunately.

Comment: @vapry no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Magento use Eav attribute structure for product and category.

In, magento ***you cannot get all field fully  as per as your requirement***.

if you a product /category collection then using `addAttributeToSelect('*')` you can get most of field values.

but If ***enable Flat setting for category and product*** then *`only get those attributes which are selected for flat selected`*

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($collection as $eachProduct){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($eachProduct->getData());
}
```

**getData()** is able to give you an array with index contain of attribute code and value give you the corresponding attribute value of product.

Comment: What about CMS Page? Can i get just list of fields that cms_page contains?